# How do I add a list to my Entity Data Model?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, entity-framework, model

I've created an Entity and I need an entry which lists multiple sizes, i.e. L, M, X, W, that i can later map through from my client to display available sizes.

My data model:

```
namespace API.Entities
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public long Price { get; set; }
        public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public int QuantityInStock { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Seed data example

```
                new Product
                {
                    Name = "Shirt",
                    Description ="Text.",
                    Price = 20000,
                    PictureUrl = "url",
                    Brand = "Brand",
                    Type = "Shirt",
                    QuantityInStock = 10,
                },
```

Tried adding 'public List Sizes { get; set; }' and then 'Sizes = {"L", "M", "XL"}' but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to have a separate table/entity for sizes and then create a relationship between the two.

```
namespace API.Entities
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public long Price { get; set; }
        public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public int QuantityInStock { get; set; }
        public List<ShirtSize> ShirtSizes { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ShirtSize
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int ProductId { get; set; }  //This becomes the foreign key
       public string Size { get; set; }

    }
}
```

You could also try and save it to the backend as a comma separtated list and then use an unmapped property to split it into a list for you.

```
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public long Price { get; set; }
        public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public int QuantityInStock { get; set; }
        public string Sizes { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string[] ShirtSizes { 
                                     get { return Sizes.Split(','); }
                                     set { Sizes = String.Join(',', value);}
                                    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you specify an **enum** using the enum keyword, that enum acts as a type, like a **class** or **struct** would.

Here's how you'd implement a property with a custom enum:

```
public enum _Sizes { L, M, XL };
public _Sizes Sizes{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, how do you suggest I should specify which sizes are available in my data seed? Sizes = _Sizes.L etc?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean more clearly?

Comment: Let's say shirt size M eventually runs out of stock and I don't want it listed, enums are immutable aren't they? I'd have to modify the source code every time.

Comment: You can create a list as a property, then add or remove Enum from it.